# Memory Mapped File v/s Normal File IO

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

When we talk about Memory Mapped Files, it is generally mentioned that a portion of file can be mapped to a process address space and we can do random access on it using pointers etc . I also have read at many places that I should have sufficient memory to accomodate whole file into memory. Now these are two statements which are bit confusing to me because if we have need sufficient memory for the complete file than what would be the advantage? I know about the benefits concerning extra kernel space copy of contents or fast time as data would not be block read or byte read as in case of streams etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have memory for the entire file - mmap is lazy loading, so the benefit there is you can modify a large file without having to use a lot of ram. Another neat trick is if you have to iterate over it backwards without having to chunk it.